# Ant dont upload file

Tags: maven, file, ant, upload

How to upload a file from maven ant to the server?
Preferably with Basic authorization.

The instructions are not complete:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/sandbox/antlibs/http/trunk/docs/http-antlib.html

I tried both post and httpost tags, but it can’t find the name.
"Cause: The name is undefined."

Comment: I tried this
<httppost url="http://xxxxx/upload"
 failonerror="true"
name="file"
uploadFile="D:\xxxxxx.txt"
verbose="true">
</httppost>

Comment: An Ant BuildException has occured: Problem: failed to create task or type httppost
[ERROR] Cause: The name is undefined.
[ERROR] Action: Check the spelling.
[ERROR] Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
[ERROR] Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
[ERROR]
 [ERROR] around Ant part ...<httppost uploadFile="D:\xxx.txt" name="file" failonerror="true"         url="http://xxxxxx/upload" verbose="true"></ httppost>... @ 4:194 in xxxxx.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Comment: It sounds like you haven't imported the `ant-contrib` library in your script. If you follow the installation instructions here, the `httppost` task should be recognized: https://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/index.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.